# Error Handling with WinJS

Tags: javascript, error-handling, windows-phone-8.1, promise, winjs

I'm new to Windows Phone development.
Going through the documentation I got to 'Using Promises' and probably missing something.

Trying to implement the code in the tutorial:
[How to handle errors with promises (HTML)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh700337.aspx)

```
(function () {
"use strict";

var app = WinJS.Application;
var activation = Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation;

app.onactivated = function (args) {
    if (args.detail.kind === activation.ActivationKind.launch) {
        if (args.detail.previousExecutionState !== activation.ApplicationExecutionState.terminated) {

        } else {

        }
        args.setPromise(WinJS.UI.processAll());
    }

    WinJS.Utilities.ready(function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('inputUrl');
        input.addEventListener('change', changeHandler);
    }, false);
};

app.oncheckpoint = function (args) {

};

function changeHandler(e) {
    var input = e.target;
    var resultDiv = document.getElementById("result");
    var div2 = document.getElementById("div2");

    WinJS.xhr({url: e.target.value})
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.status === 200) {
                resultDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
                resultDiv.innerText = "Success";
            }
            return result;
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            if (result.status === 200) {
                resultDiv.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
            }
        },
        function (e) {
            resultDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";

            if (e.message != undefined) resultDiv.innerText = e.message;
            else if (e.statusText != undefined) resultDiv.innerText = e.statusTExt;
            else resultDiv.innerText = 'Error';
        }); 
}

app.start();
})();
```

1. If I write a simple string and not URL format i'm getting an unhanded exception. Where I thought that all exceptions will be handled by then() second parameter.
2. Don't really understand the difference between the XHR code above or this alternative:

   ```
    WinJS.xhr({ url: e.target.value }).then(

       function completed(result) {
           if (result.status === 200) {
               resultDiv.style.backgroundColor = "lightGreen";
               resultDiv.innerText = "Success";
           }
       },
       function error(e) {
           resultDiv.style.backgroundColor = "red";

           if (e.message != undefined) resultDiv.innerText = e.message;
           else if (e.statusText != undefined) resultDiv.innerText = e.statusTExt;
           else resultDiv.innerText = 'Error';
       }
   )
   ```
3. At the end of the tutorial there is example for using WinJS.promise.onerror.
   I don't understand where and how to implement it.
   If someone can set an example i'll appreciate it.

Comment: I don't think all exceptions are handled by then second parameter. Usually, then second parameter is used to handle async error (like a network interruption). 
It's mean if you call an async method with bad parameters, checks of validity of these parameters are made synchronously (usually) and an exception could be directly throwed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by #1, but let me answer what I can.

First of all, if you chain promises together with multiple .then().then() calls, you need to make sure that each return value in each completed function is itself a promise. In the case of WinJS.xhr, there is only one promise involved. For this reason, your second code example is the right one, because in the first you're returning a non-promise result and attempting to attach another .then to it, which doesn't work.

Second, for Windows apps the proper practice is to use .done() for the last promise in the chain. When you have a single promise method like WinJS.xhr, use just .done().

The reason for this is that .done makes sure that exceptions that occur earlier in the chain do not get swallowed and thus disappear. It makes sure that all errors anywhere in the chain get routed to the error handler at the end.

What I think is happening with #1 as you describe it, is that if you give WinJS.xhr a non-URL, it'll throw an exception which will put the promise returned by WinJS.xhr into an error status. Your first .then() call looks for an error handler, but not seeing one, and because you're using a second unneeded .then, and aren't using .done at all, that exception doesn't surface in the promise flow and instead gets picked up by the debugger.

The purpose of WinJS.Promise.onerror is to provide a single handler for all exceptions that occur in promises. This is not useful for handling specific error cases like you're doing; it is meant more for implementing a general-purpose logger or such.

PS, I wrote a lot about promises in Appendix A "Demystifying Promises" in my free ebook, [Programming Windows Store Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, 2nd Edition](http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The code I write is as shown by the tutorial. (I added the link at the beginning). I also created the example with the done function but still getting unhanded exception if I write something that is not in URL format